# Matlab: creating a (k+1)-tensor from a list of k-tensors

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Assume you are given a bunch of k-tensors, for simplicity let's say they are 2-tensors/matrices:

```
 X = rand(5,5); Y = rand(5,5);
```

Is there an idiom for combining them into a 3-tensor, where the first dimension indexes the matrix? One way to do it is

```
P(1,:,:) = X;
P(2,:,:) = Y;
```

and now P has dimensions `2x5x5` as required. Is there a better way to do this?
For example, in numpy one could simply type:

```
P = array((X,Y))
```

but in matlab typing `P=[X Y]` or `P=[X; Y]` would give `10x5` and `5x10` matrices respectively rather than the intended `2x5x5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html) command.

Suppose you have 5 matrices of size `(x,y,z)`,

```
A = rand(x,y,z); B = rand(x,y,z); C = rand(x,y,z); D = rand(x,y,z); E = rand(x,y,z);
```

The concatenated matrix will be

```
M = cat(4, A, B, C, D, E);
```

where `4` refers to the 4-th dimension. The output `M` has size `(x,y,z,5)`. In MATLAB, each of the matrices `A,B,...` has a size of `(x,y,z,1,1,...)`, i.e. their 4-th dimensional length is 1.

---

After the concatenation, it might be necessary to change the order of dimensional indices so that the first dimension is the newly-created dimension. Use the [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/permute.html) command.

```
N = permute(M, [4, 1, 2, 3]);
```

The output matrix `N` has size `(5,x,y,z)`.

---

***Edit history***

1. Changed input matrix size from `(3,3,3)` to `(x,y,z)` to clearly distinguish each dimension during concatenation and permutation.
2. Added `permute`, which was necessary in order to satisfy OP's dimensional index requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In general, cell-arrays in MATLAB are the equivalent for Python lists (they can store objects of different types), so you could  write:

```
%# combine
P = {X Y};     %# or: P = {X;Y};

%# access the elements
P{1}
P{2}
```

In this case (matrices of same size and type), and as [@rwong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970583/matlab-creating-a-k1-tensor-from-a-list-of-k-tensors/6970650#6970650) has shown, concatenating along a new dimension is probably the way to go...