# How to evaluate a vector valued function (or create vector field) on a MATLAB mesh?

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D grid set up as follows: `[X,Y,Z] = ndgrid(0:2^(-8):1)`. I would like to evaluate and perform operations with vector fields defined at each point in a MATLAB meshgrid/ ndgrid. In other words, I want to assign three-dimensional vectors to every point in a mesh and perform pointwise operations with these vectors.

Implementations such as `vec = [X.^2 ; 2*Y]` end up concatenating matrices which makes it hard to perform operations such as dot and cross products.

Is there a way I can define a vector-valued function at each point in a mesh which takes as input, the coordinates of that point (the documentation only talked about evaluation scalar functions on meshes)? Or maybe there is a simpler implementation inbuilt in MATLAB?

Honestly, anything that would allow me to avoid subbing at 2^24 points would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**Edit**
My current implementation using symbolic substitution is as follows:

```
n=256;
[X,Y,Z] = ndgrid(0:1/n:1); % declaring 3D grid.
syms x y z; % declaring position variables.
xx = [x,y,z];
r1 = norm(xx-c1); % scalar field over grid.
n1 = (xx-c1)/r1; % vector field over grid.
v1 = cross(s1,n1); % vector field over grid.
w1 = n1'*v1; % tensor field over grid.
a = dot(v1,w1); % scalar field over grid.

% subbing in the value of scalar field 'a' (symbolic) into 3D array of doubles, A.
A = zeros(n+1,n+1,n+1);
for c = 1:n+1 % X
    for d=1:n+1 % Y
        for e= 1:n+1 % Z
            A(c,d,e) = subs(a,[x,y,z],[X(c,0,0),Y(0,d,0),Z(0,0,e)]);
        end
    end
end
% use A in future computations.
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you trying to do?6

Comment: Hello, please check the edit.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6970583/52738) or [this toolbox](http://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/TensorToolbox/index-2.6.html) would help?

Comment: Update: the tensor toolbox was not what I was looking for. I ended up defining vector multiplication using for loops on MATLAB and was able to solve my problem. Thank you for your time and suggestions.